# Heisenberg Picture with a time-dependent Schrödinger Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, time-evolution

So when the Hamiltonian is time-independent, we can define the Heisenberg state vectors by evolving the Schrödinger state vectors back in time:

$$ | \psi \rangle_H = \hat{U}^\dagger (t)|\psi(t) \rangle_S=e^{i\hat{H}t} |\psi(t)\rangle_S $$

and we define operators

$$ \hat{A}_H(t) = \hat{U}^\dagger (t) \hat{A}_S \hat{U}(t)$$

which gives us the Heisenberg equation: $$ \frac{d\hat{A}_H(t)}{dt} = -i[\hat{A}_H(t),\hat{H}]. $$

If, in the Schrödinger picture, we have a time-dependent Hamiltonian, the time evolution operator is given by

$$ \hat{U}(t) = T[e^{-i \int_0^t \hat{H}(t')dt'}] $$

If I define the Heisenberg operators in the same way with the time evolution operators and calculate $ dA_H(t)/dt $ I find

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \hat{A}_H(t)=  \frac{d\hat{U}^\dagger(t)}{dt} \hat{A}_S\hat{U}(t) + \hat{U}^\dagger(t) \hat{A}_S \frac{d\hat{U}(t)}{dt} \\ = i  \hat{U}^\dagger (t) \hat{H(t)} \hat{A}_S \hat{U}(t) - i\hat{U}^\dagger (t)\hat{A}_S\hat{H}(t)\hat{U}(t). $$

At this point, I am not sure how to proceed. I can't commute $\hat{H}(t)$ through $\hat{U}(t) $ because $[\hat{H}(t),\hat{H}(t')] \neq 0$. How do I show derive Heisenberg's equation for a time-dependent Hamiltonian?

Comment: Related [122687](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122687/does-heisenberg-equation-of-motion-imply-the-schrodinger-equation-for-evolution?noredirect=1&lq=1) .

Comment: Use $H_H\equiv U^\dagger H_S U\neq H_S$, as indicated in related question.

Comment: Related [293154](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/293154/heisenberg-equation-with-time-dependent-hamiltonian).

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be replicating all the steps that Dirac utilized with foresight to define his celebrated [interaction picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_picture). As indicated in the comment, the proper relationship is already in question [122687](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122687/does-heisenberg-equation-of-motion-imply-the-schrodinger-equation-for-evolution?noredirect=1&lq=1).  The crucial point is that, as you implicitly noticed, the Heisenberg Hamiltonian is not the Schroedinger Hamiltonian, by contrast to the time-independent case.

That is, motion being a canonical transformation, the two hamiltonians are equivalent but, in general,  not equal,
$$
H_H=U^\dagger H_S U \neq H_S,
$$
evident from the Dyson expansion.

Moreover, thinking of *H* as an observable, note
$$
\frac{d H_H}{dt}= (\partial_t H_S)_H \neq 0, 
$$
not a constant of the motion.

Conversely, if you take your S-observable *A* without explicit time dependence,
(think of *x* or *p*), your final equation is sound, and merely amounts to the customary [convective term](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/301612/heisenberg-equation-of-motion/333198#333198),
$$
\frac{dA_H}{dt}= U^\dagger i[H_S,A_S]U = i[H_H,A_H],
$$ 
as it should. Adding explicit time dependence yields the additional customary explicit term $(\partial_t A_S)_H$.

Comment: What does $(\partial_tH_S)_H$ mean? Also, why do you write a normal derivative with respect to time in front of the Heissenberg Hamiltonian but a partial derivative in front of the Schrödinger Hamiltonian? Does the Schrödinger Hamiltonian depend on anything more than just time?

Comment: It means what it says: differentiate the normally time independent $H_S$ w.r.t. time, now that it has a parametric dependence on it, and *then* perform the Heisenberg equivalence transform exemplified in the first formula here. One normally uses full derivatives to contrast the intrinsic versus the convective term, as illustrated.

Comment: Well, okay, thank you for the explanation, but I don't agree that that is what it "says". To me it's just an expression that has been given the label $H$, until I understand how to read it, but you answer me as if it is obvious how to interpret what you have written. Do you mean that $(\partial_tH_S)_H = U^\dagger\partial_tH_SU$?

Comment: Yes, of course; mainstream notation, unexceptional used.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: But don't write of course! While this might be obvious to you, please understand that this is not obvious to anyone who hasn't seen the notation before. I hadn't, so to me it was not obvious.

Comment: Apologies; but isn't this  the question's second formula, subsequently amended by the fourth?

Answer (score 1):

simply insert $UU^\dagger$ in between $H$ and $A_S$ in both term, here is the first term

$U^\dagger H A_sU=U^\dagger H U U^\dagger A_sU=H_HA_H$

Answer (score 0):

From the Schrodinger Equation and rearranging under the assumption that the kets are time independent, we know $\frac{dU(t)}{dt} = -iH(t)U(t)$, or equivalently $\frac{dU^\dagger(t)}{dt} = iU^\dagger(t) H(t)$ (this is the crux of the problem here, so far as I can tell, and a piece that was incorrect in your original question)

Carrying out $\frac{dA_H(t)}{dt}$ as you did, we now have

$$ \frac{dA_H(t)}{dt} = i U^\dagger(t)H(t)A_SU(t) - i U^\dagger(t) A_S H(t)U(t) + \frac{\partial A_H(t)}{dt} \\
= U^\dagger(t)(i \left[H(t),A_S\right])U(t) + \frac{\partial A_H(t)}{dt}$$

When $U(t)$ does not commute with $H(t)$, I believe that this is as far as you can take things. If $U(t)$ does commute with $H(t)$, then we recover the Heisenberg equation and replace $A_S$ by $A_H(t)$, as we would expect.

Comment: Ideally you would like to transform to a frame where you have a time independent Hamiltonian, or do something like a transformation to the Interaction Picture where you can treat part of it as time independent. Unfortunately it may not always possible to find a totally time independent frame (I do not have a proof of this claim, someone please correct me if I am wrong).

Answer (score -1):

From

$$
\frac{dU}{dt} = -iH(t) U(t)
$$

I would write

$$
\frac{dU^{\dagger}}{dt} = \biggl(-iH(t) U(t)\biggr)^{\dagger} = iU^{\dagger}(t) H(t).
$$

Notice that this is different from what you have.